# Creating a simple dictionary app

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I'm new on android programming and I can say that these are my first basic steps on the way.  I want to create a simple dictionary which has searching behavior. The reason of posting this question is that I want to learn the way. What are the steps of creating such an app. I'm not asking for coding but just some advises on life cycle for creating such kind of app.

Thanks from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to suggest that you consider the following step

1. use JSON for your data. Store it in assets.
   It can look something like this.

   ```
   {
      words: [
         {
             "word": "meaning of this word"
         },
         {
            //etc
         }
      ]    
   }
   ```
2. Read the JSON file into a hashmap
3. Have a EditText for the user to input a word
4. Use the hashmap to return the meaning. Display it in a TextView accordingly. Otherwise, display a not found message or to use a Toast